# rails controller actions not executing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build my first rails application but after adding authentication
I am having problems with my controllers.
I've used the rails scaffold command to implement my Tutor model. After I added authentication I cannot edit and update my Tutor and cannot see Tutor detail. 
I get the following error message 'Unknown action - The action '2' could not be found for TutorsController'
Any idea or  help? 
Find below my Tutor controller.Thanks

```
class TutorsController < ApplicationController
before_action :confirm_logged_in
before_action :set_tutor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /tutors
# GET /tutors.json
def index
@tutors = Tutor.all
end

# GET /tutors/1
# GET /tutors/1.json
def show
end

# GET /tutors/new
def new
@tutor = Tutor.new
end

# GET /tutors/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /tutors
# POST /tutors.json
def create
@tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @tutor.save
     format.html { redirect_to @tutor, notice: 'Tutor was successfully  created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tutor }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @tutor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /tutors/1
 # PATCH/PUT /tutors/1.json
 def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @tutor.update(tutor_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @tutor, notice: 'Tutor was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tutor }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @tutor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

# DELETE /tutors/1
# DELETE /tutors/1.json
def destroy
 @tutor.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to tutors_url, notice: 'Tutor was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_tutor
  @tutor = Tutor.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def tutor_params
  params.require(:tutor).permit(:nome, :cognome, :email, :telefono)
end
end
```

I am adding my  routing:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'access#login'
  get 'home' => 'home#index'
  get 'admin' => 'access#index'
  get '/dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get,:post]
  resources :disciplinas
  resources :associaziones
  resources :tutors
  resources :bambinos
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb`? It's likely you have a routing issue.

Comment: I 've added the routing above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get rid of this line:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get,:post]
```

It's not clear why it's there, but it's matching anything that the prior routes are not picking up. This means anything below that line will never get matched.

From [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.